# Add 1 when page, scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

I am using the following code for adding 1 to js variables. but it always show same result.

**javascript**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var lmp = 5,
      lma = 0;
       if($(document).height() - 50 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
          $('.div').append('<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>');
         lmp++;
         lma++;
       console.log(lmp +" : "+ lma);  
       }
   });
```

jsfiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/n75epL5u/     **check the console for results**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variables *outside* of your scroll event. Otherwise you're initializing them on every scroll.

```
var lmp = 5, lma = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).height() - 50 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
    $('.div').append('<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>');
    lmp++;
    lma++;
    console.log(lmp + " : " + lma);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason why your code is not working?**

Each time when you scroll the variables get declared.

**Solution**

Move variable declaration outside the function.

```
var lmp = 5,
    lma = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(document).height() - 50 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
      $('.div').append('<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>');
      lmp++;
      lma++;
      console.log(lmp + " : " + lma);
    }
  });
```

**[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/n75epL5u/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please move your variables outside the scroll event handler. Further its better to wrap your code in an anonymous function so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace...

```
;(function() {
   var lmp = 5, lma = 0;

   $(window).scroll(function() {
       if ($(document).height() - 50 <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
       $('.div').append('<div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>');
       lmp++;
       lma++;
       console.log(lmp + " : " + lma);
   });
}());
```